# How to use Community Startup tabs (CST) in pentaho CDE?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-ctools

I am using Pentaho version 5.0.1 stable.
I am creating a dashboard which would be user specific. As the user login's, respective dashboard will open. So a user would not need to go through browse and then open the dashboard.
The user authentication and role management is required.
I know this is possible using CST- community startup tabs as per http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cst.html

But I am not able to figure out how  install it in Pentaho and use it. There is no pluggin available at the market place.

Is there a way out? 
All i want is to install CST and use it.

Or any other pluggin or way to meet this requirement.

As I am new to pentaho environment, please guide me in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CST doesn't work for Pentaho 5.

AFAIK, there's no way to implement that requirement in Pentaho 5.

Our first plan was not to migrate CST for Pentaho 5 since we thought not many people were using it but we've been receiving some requests. There's a JIRA open requesting the migration:

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-11624.

Vote for it, comment and/or offer to sponsor the development and make the issue priority go up.

Answer (score 2):

CST support for pentaho version 5.x is now available.
You can go to market place and install it. Once install correctly, you will get the option under tools as shown in the image.
Also, to understand more about tabs you can visit: http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cst/#section=example

[image]